# Twitter API 1.1 using twitter4j

Tags: android, twitter, twitter-oauth, twitter4j

I setup my API keys a couple days ago, got my Android mobile app working with twitter4j yesterday, but today the app's twitter feed stopped working without any changes to the following code:

```
ArrayList<Tweet> tweets = new ArrayList<Tweet>();

    try {

        ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
        cb.setDebugEnabled(true)
                .setOAuthConsumerKey("xxx")
                .setOAuthConsumerSecret("xxx")
                .setOAuthAccessToken("xxx")
                .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret("xxx");
        TwitterFactory tf = new TwitterFactory(cb.build());
        Twitter twitter = tf.getInstance();

        Query query = new Query(searchTerm);
        query.setCount(count);

        QueryResult result = twitter.search(query);
        for (Status status : result.getTweets()) {

            //Log.d(TAG, "Screen Name " + status.getUser().getScreenName());

            Tweet tweet = new Tweet(
                    status.getUser().getScreenName().toString(),                //from_user
                    status.getText().toString(),                                //"text"
                    status.getUser().getBiggerProfileImageURL().toString(),     //"profile_image_url"
                    status.getCreatedAt().toString());                          //"created_at"
            tweets.add(tweet);
        }
    }
    catch (TwitterException e)
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "Error " + e.toString());
    }

    return tweets;
```

Populated with the correct OAuth keys, this is the TwitterException that is generated:

```
06-23 10:04:32.729: W/System.err(26432):     org.apache.http.client.HttpResponseException: Gone
```

06-23 10:04:32.729: W/System.err(26432):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler.handleResponse(BasicResponseHandler.java:71)
06-23 10:04:32.734: W/System.err(26432):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler.handleResponse(BasicResponseHandler.java:59)
06-23 10:04:32.734: W/System.err(26432):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:773)
06-23 10:04:32.739: W/System.err(26432):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:743)
06-23 10:04:32.739: W/System.err(26432):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:732)
06-23 10:04:32.739: W/System.err(26432):    at com.campbellgolf.app.UTILS.ProxyNetworkTwitter.getTweets(ProxyNetworkTwitter.java:34)
06-23 10:04:32.739: W/System.err(26432):    at com.campbellgolf.app.UI.ActivityTwitterFeed$1.run(ActivityTwitterFeed.java:175)
06-23 10:04:32.739: W/System.err(26432):    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:442)
06-23 10:04:32.739: W/System.err(26432):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRunAndReset(FutureTask.java:322)
06-23 10:04:32.739: W/System.err(26432):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:149)
06-23 10:04:32.739: W/System.err(26432):    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:150)
06-23 10:04:32.744: W/System.err(26432):    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:265)
06-23 10:04:32.744: W/System.err(26432):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
06-23 10:04:32.744: W/System.err(26432):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
06-23 10:04:32.744: W/System.err(26432):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

Answer (score 1):

I used [socialauth-android 2.5](http://code.google.com/p/socialauth-android/) sdk couple of days ago after getting issue with twitter4j. It seems that they have ported it to 1.1 for twitter.

i was able to make tweets and access other functionalists.

Comment: Thanks!  I'm not bound to using twitter4j, so I'll check out socialauth-android as you've suggested.

zest - what works for you now, twitter4j or socialauth?  My twitter4j implementation above, still doesn't work.